# vimeo embed showing black screen on firefox?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, vimeo

I embed videos into my web site, works great in all browsers but on firefox shows up a black screen, any idea? Using the iframe mode. Funniest thing is that some show up and some don't using the same embed method for all.

Comment: hang on a minute! can you believe that now they work? why?!?! i haven't touched anything! and other users were experiencing the same thing as i did but other users were saying they were able to see the videos? wtf!? this is to drive mad developers dear vimeo boys and girls! firefox latest verision btw

Comment: I was looking at your videos thinking they mostly seem to work and I couldn't figure out the problem. I did notice that occasionally (I zoomed Firefox out as far as it would go to see the page easily) the video would load a black background but if I switched to another tab and back it would then show the image, I wonder if it's some CSS z-index/flash wmode issue?

Comment: haven't got any z-index in there or it shouldn't be using wmode, not setting it myself anyway. However iframe is for universal player and it should automatically check if it can use html5 or flash version but it doesn't seem to work: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i came up with using this:

In the main page I have a element which i then populate and replace with the iframe. Thanks

Main page:

```
<span class="video clearfix" data-vimeoid="<?php echo the_field('vimeo') ?>"></span>
```

Content page to be loaded:

```
var url = this.href + " .content";
var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {

        'frameborder' : 0,

        'width' : '692',

        'height' : '389',

        'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ videoSpan.data("vimeoid") +'?autoplay=0&api=1'

});

videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
```

Answer (score 1):

rob.m - yup, showing and hiding vimeo videos will cause that random black screen to appear. I JUST ran into this on a project, and tore my hair out for the better part of a day figuring out why.

If you NEED to show/hide videos, and you NEED the black screen to not show up, you will have to use the old school flash embed. That will work.

It's a trade off - consistent embed images = flash OR inconsistent embed images = universal method (read: HTML5 w/ flash fallback).

[Brief rant: the Vimeo API documentation leaves a LOT to be desired]

If you need to further interact with these videos that you show/hide, and plan to use the Vimeo API to do so, I found that I had to use the SWFobjects library method. See this forum post for more: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:44521  - specifically, the second to last post.

Comment: thanks but what about ipad and iphone tho? I'm loading the iframe on an ajax call which fadesIn once the box has expanded, I could try to load the video once its box is expanded and avoid "initially hidden" as they say (?)