# vimeo html 5 player not showing

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Anyone have an idea?

I am using this http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player#universal

on a right click on the player i only see the flash in my own embed code using their universal player. This si what I have:

```
 <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Testing with latest chrome.

Comment: Post code so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: i have posted a link to their documentation which demonstrates the code i am using but question is now updated with the code.

Comment: Yeah I can see the link, but I can't see what you've done. Perhaps you need to enter a width, height and video id.

Comment: just re updated, but to be honest i'm doing exactly as they say, or am i not? p.s. getting the id via php, works fine, it's just that html5 version won't show up. Here it is the live link, click on a content box to expand and rigth click the video to see it's only displaying flash version: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/

Comment: Right I see what you mean, well a bit of searching through their forums seems to suggest that HTML5 is used as a fallback rather than the other way round. So if you're browser supports flash, it might think that's the best player.

Comment: Also check out this link: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:47357#comment_6560060 One of the comments says "You need to be using the HTML5 player on Vimeo.com to see HTML5 video embedded elsewhere. The iframe-based embed code dynamically switches between HTML5 and Flash depending on your preference on the site."

Comment: actually guess what? try to go here: http://vimeo.com/35912908 and on the bottom right of the video do "switch to html5" if you see that means you are watching with their flash version. So switch to html5 then go to my test site and try again to right click on a video, it is now showing as html5. Which means they must be using cookies or something

Comment: ha! said the same thing at the same time :)

Comment: now only wish i had an ipad or an iphone to test if the videos on my site are watchable or not

Comment: So it's basically at the users discretion what they will see on your site which I guess is the purpose of the universal player. Glad you know what's going on.

Comment: Wonder if that will really auto detect ipad and iphone as they say by reading around tho. Thanks a lot man, if you want to put your summarised answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vimeo universal player will detect what capabilities your browser has and will fallback to either the HTML5 player or the Flash player depending on which capability you are missing.

If your browser supports both players, it will use the type of player that you have chosen to use on the Vimeo site for all embedded videos in other sites. By default (or if you don't have a Vimeo account) the Flash player will be displayed.

So in summary it is dependantly firstly on your browser capability and secondly on your preference with the Vimeo site.

Comment: No idea tbh. If you right click the blank video and then play play it in Vimeo, it will start to work on your site as well, but then the interface is all messed up :/

Comment: well even in this case i think i've found the cause and the solution, read bottom comments and last answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203486/vimeo-embed-showing-black-screen-on-firefox